# Django - obtaining a child model from a parent by the childs one to one field?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Good Afternoon,

I have a pair of models like the below:

```
class DeviceCircuitSubnets(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    circuit = models.ForeignKey(Circuit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    subnet = models.ForeignKey(Subnet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class BGPData(models.Model):
    device_circuit_subnet = models.OneToOneField(DeviceCircuitSubnets, verbose_name="Device", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bgp_peer_as = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='BGP Peer AS', blank=True, null=True)
    bgp_session = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='BGP Session', blank=True, null=True)
    bgp_routes = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='BGP Routes Received', blank=True, null=True)
    service_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Service Status', blank=True, null=True)  
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

I am filtering the DeviceCircuitSubnets and then I also want to access the BGPData related model via each filtered item.

```
service_data = DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(monitored=True, device__site_id=site_id) \
                                            .select_related('device','circuit','subnet')
```

I have tried adding bgpdata to the select related and to prefetch but neither are currently working, I am returned with an error stating the model doesn't exist.

how would my query need to look to obtain each one to one field in a query set?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't set [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) attribute on `OneToOneField`, you need to use lower-cased model name for reverse relation:

```
service_data = DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(monitored=True, device__site_id=site_id) \
                                            .select_related('bgpdata')
```

Note also that:

> A DoesNotExist exception is raised when accessing the reverse relationship if an entry in the related table doesn’t exist